# How to pass uri to set wallpaper in whatsapp

Tags: android, wallpaper, whatsapp

How to set wallpaper of whatsapp through a drawable image in my app. From below code I am able to share image on whatsapp not set as wallpaper.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackagename/"+R.drawable.image);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```